# change of basis and inverse in tensor notation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, notation

I'm trying to study tensors from several textbooks. I would like it
if someone could confirm my understanding of a particular easy example.
It is from Itskov, *Tensor Algebra and Tensor Analysis for Engineers,* 3rd edition.

$\mathbf{e}_i$ is an orthonormal basis, and $\mathbf{g}_i$ is some other basis.
$\mathbf{e}^i$ and $\mathbf{g}^i$ are the respective dual bases.

Itskov expresses the "primal" bases in terms of each other (eq. 1.16):

> $\mathbf{e}_i = \alpha_i^j \, \mathbf{g}_j    \quad\text{and}\quad  \mathbf{g}_i = \beta_i^j \,\mathbf{e}_j$

Ok, no problem so far.

Itskov then says ``Let further'' (eq. 1.19):

> $\mathbf{g}^i = \alpha^i_{\,j} \, \mathbf{e}^j$

My question:  I believe that this $\alpha^i_{\,j}$ is a *different* thing than the $\alpha_i^j$ in 1.16;
I think I should regard these as matrix inverses of each other. 
However the notation almost suggests that they could be the same numbers, just indexed differently.

One possible little clue, the subscript $j$ in 1.19 is displaced slightly (which I tried to reproduce here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your notation, suppose $g^{i} = \sum_{j}\beta^{i}_{j}e^{j}$.

Then $$\beta^{i}_{j} = g^{i}(e_{j}) = g^{i}(\sum_{k}\alpha^{k}_{j}g_{k}) = \sum_{k}\alpha^{k}_{j}\cdot g^{i}(g_{k}) = \alpha_{j}^{i}$$

So $\beta^{i}_{j} = \alpha_{j}^{i}$

Comment: 1) I'm guessing the first step $B_j^i = g^i(e_j)$ is obtained by multiplying on the right with $e_j$.  The rest I follow.

Comment: $\beta_{i}^{j} = g^{i}(e_{j}) $ is obtained by applying the linear functional $g^{i}$ to the vector $e_{j}$

Comment: Initially I felt that the $a_i^j$ is like a matrix, and thus the two equations are analogous to matrix vector equations $e = A g$ and $g = A e$, with $A$ being the matrix corresponding to $a_i^j$.  This makes no sense, so it seemed that $a_i^j$ must have different meaning in the two equations.  However I now think the resolution is that $a_i^j$ is indeed the same in both (thanks to WLOG's answer), but the difference is absorbed in $g_i$ versus  $g^i$.